# Devuan chimaera apt is not working

Tags: devuan

```
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
Err:5 http://deb.devuan.org/merged chimaera/main i386 libmagickwand-6.q16-6 i386 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3+deb11u1
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/pool/DEBIAN/main/libh/libheif/libheif1_1.11.0-1_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/pool/DEBIAN/main/libl/liblqr/liblqr-1-0_0.4.2-2.1_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/pool/DEBIAN-SECURITY/updates/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick-6-common_6.9.11.60%2bdfsg-1.3%2bdeb11u1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/pool/DEBIAN-SECURITY/updates/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore-6.q16-6_6.9.11.60%2bdfsg-1.3%2bdeb11u1_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/pool/DEBIAN/main/c/chafa/chafa_1.6.0-1_i386.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.devuan.org/merged/pool/DEBIAN/main/n/neofetch/neofetch_7.1.0-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.devuan.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and this with any package what i want install

Comment: You could try something "simpler": `ping google.com` and if that fails, `ping 8.8.8.8`. Are these two commands working? Only the 2nd? None?

Comment: all of this commands work

Comment: OK. So there is network there is DNS (or some of it), but somehow apt-get doesn't appear to be able to resolve DNS. I have no further idea. Maybe you know your system has special setups that would interfere?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your DNS setup. Testing name resolution of deb.devuan.org seems to be OK today and seems not to have changed since four days.

To test your setup, use

```
dig +short deb.devuan.org
```

which tries to resolve the name using your currently set resolvers and

```
dig +short deb.devuan.org @9.9.9.9
```

to use [Quad9](https://quad9.org/). Both command should resolve the name to a bunch of addresses. If not debug the name resolving capabilities of the concerned host.

It may be better anyway to [chose a mirror](https://pkgmaster.devuan.org/mirror_list.txt) which is close to you instead of using the round robin mechanism of deb.devuan.org. Once chosen modify your /etc/apt/sources.list to use your new mirror server, e.g. from the Friedrich-Alexander-Universität, Erlangen-Nürnberg, Germany it would look like:

```
# Devuan GNU+Linux chimaera

deb https://ftp.fau.de/devuan/merged chimaera main contrib non-free
deb https://ftp.fau.de/devuan/merged chimaera-updates main contrib non-free
deb https://ftp.fau.de/devuan/merged chimaera-security main contrib non-free
deb https://ftp.fau.de/devuan/merged chimaera-backports main contrib non-free
```

Note: The example shows a mirror supporting https, which is preferred.

The [current state of the Devuan mirror network](http://veritas.devuan.org/apt-panopticon/results/Report-web.html) is published every 5 minutes.